# Stylish signup Form plugin for WordPress

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I am looking for a plugin to build a form like this one:  https://8fit.com/signup

We are using formidable form and Gravity forms right now, but neither of them allow such styling options.

Answer (score 0):

Gravity forms yet not give any option to style forms but they [recommended free plugin](https://docs.gravityforms.com/changing-font-sizes/) for flexible styling. you can download or see by [clicking here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/styles-and-layouts-for-gravity-forms/). Formidable forms have plugin for styling which is premium. [See here](https://formidableforms.com/features/wordpress-visual-form-styler/)